# How to monitor and block ajax requests in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, ajax, swift, macos, wkwebview

From my understanding and trying out some code, we can only monitor page navigation requests using

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)
{
    if // some condition
    {
        decisionHandler(.allow) // to allow the page navigation.
    }
    else
    {
        decisionHandler(.cancel) // to cancel the page navigation.
    }
}
```

But is there any way to monitor and block some ajax requests in WKWebView?

And also to capture the ajax response.

Comment: Facing kind of the same problem have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @jailani Nope..

Comment: Did you consider injecting a user script which overwrites the `XMLHttpRequest` object with a custom proxy object? It should work similar to [bridging web notifications to a native app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615934/769502).