# How to capture notifications in a WKWebView?

Tags: swift, macos, webkit, web-notifications

I'm working on a macOS desktop app in Swift 4.
It has a WKWebView which loads up a web page that sends notifications.
None of the notifications are shown by default and there's also no permission request.

I need a way to show the notifications and intercept them, so that I can show a counter.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You found solution?

Comment: @MICKAELBELHASSEN I'm afraid not

Answer (score 19):

I was facing the same challenge and solved it by injecting a script ([`WKUserScript`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscript)) which overrides the web notification API with a custom implementation that leverages the [`WKUserContentController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller) to send messages to the native app code which posts the final notifications in the end.

## Setting up `WKWebView`

Programmatic creation of a `WKWebView` is necessary to use a custom `WKWebViewConfiguration` as far as I know. Creating a new macOS app project I extend my `viewDidLoad` in the `ViewController` function like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userScriptURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "UserScript", withExtension: "js")!
    let userScriptCode = try! String(contentsOf: userScriptURL)
    let userScript = WKUserScript(source: userScriptCode, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
    configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "notify")
    
    let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Document", withExtension: "html")!
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: configuration)
    webView.loadFileURL(documentURL, allowingReadAccessTo: documentURL)
    
    view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

First I load the user script from the app bundle and add it to the user content controller. I also add a message handler called `notify` which can be used to phone back from the JavaScript context to native code. At the end I load an example HTML document from the app bundle and present the web view using the whole area available in the window.

## Overriding the Notification API

This is the injected user script and a partial override of the web [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification). It is sufficient to handle [the typical notification permission request process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Example) and posting of notifications in scope of this generic question.

```
/**
 * Incomplete Notification API override to enable native notifications.
 */
class NotificationOverride {
    // Grant permission by default to keep this example simple.
    // Safari 13 does not support class fields yet, so a static getter must be used.
    static get permission() {
        return "granted";
    }
    
    // Safari 13 still uses callbacks instead of promises.
    static requestPermission (callback) {
        callback("granted");
    }
    
    // Forward the notification text to the native app through the script message handler.
    constructor (messageText) {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.notify.postMessage(messageText);
    }
}

// Override the global browser notification object.
window.Notification = NotificationOverride;
```

Every time a new notification is created in the JavaScript context, the user content controller message handler is invoked.

## Handling the Script Message

The `ViewController` (or whatever else should handle the script messages) needs to conform to [`WKScriptMessageHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler) and implement the following function to handle invocations:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "WKWebView Notification Example"
        content.body = message.body as! String
        
        let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: nil)

        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog(error.debugDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

The whole implementation is about the creation of a local, native notification in macOS. It does not work yet without additional effort, though.

## App Delegate Adjustments

Before a macOS app is allowed to post notifications, it must request the permissions to do so, like a website.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }
    }
```

If notifications should be presented while the app is in the foreground, the app delegate must be extended further to conform to [`UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate) and implement:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
    }
```

which requires the delegate assignment in `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)`:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

The [`UNNotificationPresentationOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptions) may vary according to your requirements.

Comment: Your solution works but is unfortunately not usable with webviews like WhatsApp or Facebook messenger, or most web pages that send notifications. Because before sending the notification the web pages first check `window.Notification.permission` if it is `denied` or `enabled`. So your solution is good only theoretically but in real web pages your solution is unusable.

Comment: I extended the user script to cover the generic authorization process. I originally considered that out of scope because the question was more about the conceptual bridging of notifications.

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen It is `granted`, not `enabled` (see [the specification](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#permission)).

Comment: Very good job, I upvoted. This is the first time someone has posted a solution to this

Comment: any reason this can't work for iOS? also, would this approach comply w/ app-store review guidelines (will apple let it through)?

Comment: It has been some years now but I think I implemented it for iOS originally in a corporate app. It should work equally. Concerning the approval: I actually do not know. And I cannot imagine why it should cause problems that the original trigger is inside a web view. It is (equal to) an app dispatching a notification locally on a device. [A standard task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app).