# How to enable web notifications from WKWebView in Swift?

Tags: swift, webview, notifications, wkwebview

Hello I have an application with several webviews. I would like to intercept web notifications and print them in the console.

I have already written JavaScript code to intercept web notifications and print them.

The problem is that I feel that we can not enable web notifications in a WKWebView. When I inject `window.Notification.permission` i always get `default` or `denied`. I would like to get `granted`, how can I grant permission to enable the webview?

I just need to know how to allow `window.Notification` because all the rest of my code is ready, that is the only thing I miss.

I know that with UIWebView it is possible but deprecated so I do not want to use it. For UIWebview there is a private API `WebNotificationProvider`, is there an equivalent for WKWebView?

I've been looking for a few weeks and can not find a solution.

Comment: You might consider overriding `window.Notification` to invoke a script message handler as I proposed in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615934/769502).

Comment: I have commented your post