# iOS Expose Custom API to WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

On Android, I am using the [`addJavascriptInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) method to expose a custom API to webpages I load in a [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Is there a similar alternative for the iOS [`WKWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)?

I came across [`evaluateJavaScript`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) which allows me to run JavaScript to add my API to the global scope, but I can't figure out a way of adding code that communicates with my app.

Comment: From what I understand you are trying to make javascript communicate with a Webview. I tried to do the same things as you and it worked on Android but not on IOS. There is a way to make them communicate but it's trough only one function. There is a big article that explains it pretty well https://medium.com/@JillevdWeerd/creating-links-between-wkwebview-and-native-code-8e998889b503

Comment: @GilbertGabriel Thanks that looks like what I need

Comment: No problem! I wrote an answer so if the article fills the needs then feel free to accept it otherwise tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to communicate from a WKWebview to the code but only with one function and it is pretty hard to do but if you manage everything well you can come up with good results. I will let this article explain it because it is a pretty complex process and they will do it better then me.

[Creating links between WKWebView and native code](https://medium.com/@JillevdWeerd/creating-links-between-wkwebview-and-native-code-8e998889b503)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. You probably are looking for [`WKScriptMessageHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler). Create a custom configuration for the web view. For example in your view controller's `viewDidLoad`.

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
```

Register a script message handler with the configuration. For example a view controller, which creates the `WKWebView` on `viewDidLoad`. The view controller then needs to conform to `WKScriptMessageHandler`.

```
configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "helloworld")
```

Programmatically create the web view with the custom configuration.

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: configuration)
```

Call the WebKit message handler from JavaScript. Message handlers are available as properties in the global `window.webkit.messageHandlers` object. properties use the name used when calling [`WKUserContentController.add(_:name:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller/1537172-add) above.

```
window.webkit.messageHandlers.helloworld.postMessage("Hi!");
```

Handle the call from the JavaScript context.

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message.body as! String)
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I copied and reduced this code snippets from [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615934/769502) to a higher level question of which the solution includes these steps.